# Maven Jenkins Build Failure

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I try to build my Jenkins project but have the same problem all the time.
I can't understand where it coming from. I will appreciate all kind of help. Tnx!!!!

cd C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20" cmd /c "\"\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat\" -Dmaven.ext.class.path=\"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar\" clean install\"\""
Scanning for projects...

---

### Building Jenkins CLI 1.583-SNAPSHOT

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ cli ---
Deleting C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ cli ---

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:display-info (display-info) @ cli ---
Maven Version: 3.0.5
JDK Version: 1.8.0_20 normalized as: 1.8.0-20
OS Info: Arch: amd64 Family: dos Name: windows 7 Version: 6.1

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (default) @ cli ---
Adding ignore: org.eclipse.jetty.spdy.*

--- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0.1:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) @ cli ---

--- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:timestamp-property (timestamp-property) @ cli ---
Setting property 'now' to '10/02/2014 15:16 GMT'.

--- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:regex-property (version-property) @ cli ---
Setting property 'build.version' to '1.583-SNAPSHOT (private-10/02/2014 15:16 GMT-ystavcha)'.

--- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ cli ---
Source directory: C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\generated-sources\localizer added.

--- gmaven-plugin:1.5-jenkins-1:generateStubs (default) @ cli ---
No sources found for Java stub generation

--- maven-localizer-plugin:1.15:generate (default) @ cli ---

--- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2.1:process (default) @ cli ---

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cli ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 7 resources
Copying 1 resource

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @ cli ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 10 source files to C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\classes

--- gmaven-plugin:1.5-jenkins-1:compile (default) @ cli ---
No sources found to compile

--- animal-sniffer-maven-plugin:1.9:check (default) @ cli ---
Checking unresolved references to org.codehaus.mojo.signature:java16:1.0

--- gmaven-plugin:1.5-jenkins-1:generateTestStubs (default) @ cli ---
No sources found for Java stub generation

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ cli ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
Copying 4 resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ cli ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\test-classes

--- gmaven-plugin:1.5-jenkins-1:testCompile (default) @ cli ---
No sources found to compile

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) @ cli ---
Surefire report directory: C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\surefire-reports

---

### T E S T S

```
Running hudson.cli.ConnectionMockTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.36 sec - in hudson.cli.ConnectionMockTest
Running hudson.cli.ConnectionTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.13 sec - in hudson.cli.ConnectionTest
Running hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.48 sec <<< FAILURE! - in hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest
initializationError(hudson.cli.PrivateKeyProviderTest)  Time elapsed: 0.02 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name hudson.cli.CLI. Reason: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3508)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3497)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3402)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:144)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:204)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:304)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:319)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.compareSignature(MemberResolver.java:248)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:120)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:97)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:711)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr$ProceedForNew.setReturnType(NewExpr.java:244)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:147)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:249)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:218)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:39)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:405)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:428)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:212)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1385)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:75)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:203)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3508)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3497)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3402)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:144)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1113)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1056)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:150)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:765)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:109)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:191)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:304)
    at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:319)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.compareSignature(MemberResolver.java:248)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:120)
    at javassist.compiler.MemberResolver.lookupMethod(MemberResolver.java:97)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:711)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr$ProceedForNew.setReturnType(NewExpr.java:244)
    at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:147)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atVariableAssign(TypeChecker.java:249)
    at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atAssignExpr(TypeChecker.java:218)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.AssignExpr.accept(AssignExpr.java:39)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atIfStmnt(CodeGen.java:405)
    at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:355)
    at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
    at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:569)
    at javassist.expr.NewExpr.replace(NewExpr.java:207)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer$PowerMockExpressionEditor.edit(MainMockTransformer.java:428)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.loopBody(ExprEditor.java:212)
    at javassist.expr.ExprEditor.doit(ExprEditor.java:91)
    at javassist.CtClassType.instrument(CtClassType.java:1385)
    at org.powermock.core.transformers.impl.MainMockTransformer.transform(MainMockTransformer.java:75)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java:203)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:145)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:439)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
    at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3508)
    at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3497)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3402)
    at org.junit.internal.MethodSorter.getDeclaredMethods(MethodSorter.java:52)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClass.getAnnotatedMethods(TestClass.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateTestMethods(MethodValidator.java:71)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateStaticMethods(MethodValidator.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.validateMethodsForDefaultRunner(MethodValidator.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.validate(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:108)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.<init>(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:144)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:21)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:26)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:262)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  PrivateKeyProviderTest.initializationError » IllegalState Failed to transform ...
```

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

---

### BUILD FAILURE

Total time: 9.509s
Finished at: Thu Oct 02 11:16:09 EDT 2014

### Final Memory: 19M/270M

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project cli: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\ystavcha\Desktop\newClone\jenkins\cli\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells you:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test (default-test) on project cli: There are test failures

There are test failures.

Secondly, looks like you are not running a maven-style job. Instead, you created a free-style job and hardcoded the `mvn` command into it.

Comment: I created a freestyle job on my local system and it works fine with maven. But when I try to run the same freestyle job on an AWS virtual machine with the same configs as my local system, I get the `'mvn.bat' is not  recognized as an internal or external command` error. Although I solved it by creating a maven-style job, why does Jenkins show different behaviors on the same job in identical environments?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by downgrading my version of the JDK from 8 to 7.